# d3 redraw chart on zoom with the new, zoomed in, range

Tags: d3.js, zooming

As per the title, I'm looking to redraw my chart after the user zooms in.

I'm listening to "zoomend" which is quite handy.  The trick is, I need to refetch the data and therefore need to call a function 'above' this event listener scope.

Furthermore, I need to use the max and min of the range that the user just zoomed into.

Here's the code setting things up:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
               .x(xAsTime)
               .y(y)
               .on("zoom", zoomFunction)
               .on("zoomend", zoomEndFunction);

var svg = histogram_container.append("svg")
               .attr('class', 'chart')
               .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
               .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
               .call(zoom)
             .append('g')
               .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left +
                     ', ' + margin.top + ')');
```

My zoomFunction just does a transform:

```
function zoomFunction() {
              svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
              svg.selectAll("rect.bar").attr("transform", "translate(" +
                  d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ", 1)");
}
```

I'd like my zoomEndFunction to do something like this:

```
function zoomEndFunction() {
              // I'm trying to get hold of the parent object
              that = event.data.self; // <------ DOESN'T WORK.  HOW DO I GET 'THIS'?

              // get the minimum visible X from the scale
              that.startDate = xAxis.scale().invert(0);

              // get the maximum visible X from the scale
              that.endDate = xAxis.scale().invert(1000);

              // redraw the cart
              that.fetchDataAndRedrawChart();
}
```

UPDATE

I was able to get a big part of the puzzle.  While I tried using closure before without success it was because I was doing it incorrectly.  Here's the code that captures the parent object:

```
function zoomEndFunction(scope) {
    return function() {
        var that = scope;
        // do whatever I want with that
    }
}
```

This means that I need to change the above line from:

```
.on("zoomend", zoomEndFunction);
```

to

```
.on("zoomend", zoomEndFunction(this));
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a series of questions which all describe a certain type of d3 workflow where data is aggregated and dis-aggregated.  I plan on putting this into a block when all the parts are there.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Your `zoomEndFunction` looks like it would only need the implementation of the last function.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, thanks..  I can't seem to get a hold of the parent object's scope.  That is my "that = event.data.self" is some pseudocode (from JQuery) that doesn't work.  There is no event.data.self - I'm trapped in the svg element.

Comment: Are you looking for `this.parentNode`?

Comment: `this.parentNode` gives the DOM parent.  I'm looking for the javascript object (a function) that creates the chart.  It's where all the state lies as well as the helper functions...

Comment: So @LarsKotthoff, I've got the closure going - see the UPDATE to the question. I hope it's the most elegant way to do this..

Comment: Not sure if I understand what exactly you're trying to do anymore, but if a closure works for you then go with that.