# d3 get new x-axis endpoints after zooming

Tags: d3.js

I'm able to zoom as in [block 4015254](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254). But as per my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230700/d3-redraw-chart-on-zoom-with-the-new-zoomed-in-range) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155844/d3-zoom-into-data-not-image-in-bar-chart-or-histogram) I'm trying to zoom into the data, not the vector diagram.

I think I'm most of the way there but need a way to know what the new x-axis endpoints are.

For example, [block 4015254](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254) starts with an x-axis ranging from January 1999 to January 2003.  After zooming in a bit, the x-axis now ranges from about February 2000 to about November 2000.  Those are the endpoints I'm looking for.

I'm assuming I'll need to pass my chart's endpoints into a scaling function or d3.time.scale or d3.scale.linear.

The idea is to grab those endpoints and, upon `zoomend` recalculate the bar chart's granularity based upon the new range.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
function zoomEndFunction(scope) {
    return function() {
        var that = scope;

        var startDate = xAxis.scale()(0); // <---- this doesn't work

        var endDate = xAxis.scale()(that.chartWidth); // <---- nor this

        that.redrawChart(startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to get that using `x.domain()`.

Comment: Good point, @LarsKotthoff.  Turns out, as I described in my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206020/d3-convert-x-axis-from-array-indices-to-dates) I'm using a separate xScale to convert from my array indices to times.  As this gets more and more complex I might have to tell the boss that we need to rework the whole strategy.

Comment: For what it's worth, for now I'm doing this hack-y feeling trick: I save the inverse of the time version of my xScale as a function scoped variable which I then access in zoomEndFunction.